# Bootstrap Glyphicons not working in laravel 4

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, glyphicons

I have downloaded the twitter bootstrap files and added it to laravel's public folder under packages/boot path as

---css
---js
---fonts

I linked the stylesheets using the following code.

```
{{ HTML::style('packages/boot/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('packages/boot/css/style.css') }}
```

These style rules works fine but the glyphicons are not working. Someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap CSS is adding the required font for the glyphicons using (or similar):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Is that path pointing to the real font files? Can you give us a demo for the resulting HTML?

Comment: Yes its pointing correctly to the font files. I tried to use font awesome files using my style.css file, same issue. the icons are not appearing. Now I am using CDN links to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this the last included file:

url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg')

Work for me.